# How can I make keywords italic in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider

I would like to have my keywords (`new`, `class`, etc) be in italic, while the rest of my code remains standard.

Is there any way to do this in JetBrains IDEs, such as IntelliJ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Java

[image]